# query help in joining tables

Tags: mysql, query

I'm quite green in mysql, but I have been assigned a task for which I completely lost. I have a unique codes table in mysql and then I have another 6 tables for individual clients. I would like to extract those codes which have a value in cat_code = 'wine' from all 5 clients and item_grp_code ='00101' from 1 client since the last client has no cat_code?

Any idea how to do around this?

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  items.code, nxr.departmentcode, nxr.itemgroupcode, las.departmentcode,
  las.itemgrpdesc, las.desc1, nxr.desc1 
FROM (
retail_append.items items 
left outer JOIN 
retail_append.nxr nxr 
  ON (items.code = nxr.code)) 
left outer JOIN 
retail_append.las las 
  ON (items.code = las.code) 
WHERE (las.itemgroupcode = '00101') OR (nxr.categorycode = 'wine');
```

Comment: one thing that would help a lot is the table schema's with some example of what data is in each table.  You should be able to add those details by editing the question.  Thank you,

Comment: Will try and get a table schema, this is what I tried so far,SELECT DISTINCT items.code,
       nxr.departmentcode,
       nxr.itemgroupcode,
       las.departmentcode,
       las.itemgrpdesc,
       las.desc1,
       nxr.desc1
FROM (retail_append.items items
      left outer JOIN retail_append.nxr nxr ON (items.code = nxr.code))
     left outer JOIN retail_append.las las ON (items.code = las.code)
     WHERE (las.itemgroupcode = '00101')
OR (nxr.categorycode = 'wine');

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) then [click the Edit link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/241394/edit) to add the necessary information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the where clause to the join itself?  Something like

`left outer JOIN 
retail_append.nxr nxr 
ON (items.code = nxr.code AND nxr.categoryCode = 'wine'))` and similar for the other with the item group code?

Answer (score 0):

When you want some stuff from here and some from there, think `UNION`:

```
SELECT  items.code, nxr.departmentcode, nxr.itemgroupcode,
        las.departmentcode, las.itemgrpdesc, las.desc1, nxr.desc1
    FROM items
    JOIN  nxr       ON (items.code = nxr.code)
    LEFT JOIN  las  ON (items.code = las.code)
    WHERE  nxr.categorycode = 'wine'
UNION
SELECT  items.code, nxr.departmentcode, nxr.itemgroupcode,
        las.departmentcode, las.itemgrpdesc, las.desc1, nxr.desc1
    FROM items
    JOIN  las       ON (items.code = las.code)
    LEFT JOIN  nxr  ON (items.code = nxr.code)
    WHERE  las.itemgroupcode = '00101'
```

Note that I changed from `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` in the cases where you have a `WHERE` clause that demands the existence of a row.  Use `LEFT JOIN` (identical to `left outer join`) only when the rows in the "right" table are optional.

I removed `DISTINCT` since `UNION` does that by default.  (It is faster to do `UNION ALL`, but you might get unwanted dups.)

I did not spot anything obviously wrong with your attempt with left joins; I prefer `UNION` for *this* kind of query.  If nothing else, this may help you shed some of the 'green in mysql'.

Comment: Sorry for my late feedback your query worked 100%, thanks for the explanation, didn't know that `UNION` does the distinct. One question what is the difference between `NOT NULL` and `NOT NULL DEFAULT`

Comment: @user114246 - `NOT NULL` leaves the `DEFAULT` at a standard value (empty string, zero, etc); `DEFAULT` lets you specify what you want the default to be when an `INSERT` does not provide a value for that column.

Comment: as mentioned above your query works well, however when I tried to join all 8 tables with the `UNION` function query takes ages, is there a faster way to join all clients tables (las,twr stv etc) with the codes from the codes table in one table. I'm trying to add my database diagram but cannot find the way:(

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/pn8tbrwosv1a2y7/model.pdf?dl=0]

Comment: @user114246 - Multiple tables with identical schema -- usually not a good schema design.  Focus on combining those 9 tables into one.  (You may need an extra column to say which type each row is.)  After that, the `UNION` problem will probably go away.

Comment: something like this? [https://www.dropbox.com/s/pn8tbrwosv1a2y7/model.pdf?dl=0]

Comment: @user114246 - That's the same.

Comment: Sorry this I meant [https://www.dropbox.com/s/esi9pxe19n558pk/items%20table.pdf?dl=0]

Comment: @user114246 - Yes, try that out.  What would the `SELECT` be like for that?  On another topic, it is usually 'wrong' to have a `code` and `desc` in the same table -- except for a normalization table.  That is, you have an `id` for something sitting in various table(s), then have that `id` plus description, name, etc in another table.

Comment: My select would be the code, I was requested to have a complete table for all clients as [https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1e0ixugc1l4xbd/required%20table.xlsx?dl=0] however since I would like to learn and improve in mysql, if you could guide me with a schema diagram I will redo over the weekend, and start from scratch. Rick thanks for your patience and assistance, much appreciated.